# Listview Binding SelectedItem Grids Image how to get

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-runtime

Hi need some hep with the below problem
I am using a Listview which has a grid that contains an Image and its border .Chk the below Xaml Code

```
<ListView x:Name="listview1" MinWidth="250" MaxWidth="250"          SelectionChanged="listview1_SelectionChanged_1"
IsItemClickEnabled="True">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid Height="230" Width="220">-->
<Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="20" BorderBrush="#C6A92F" BorderThickness="4" Width="220" Height="200">
<Image x:Name="propImage" Source="{Binding}" Height="200" Width="180"/>
</Border>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>`
```

I am Binding the Images source from code behind.

My query is how to get the selectedItem's Image.

Comment: What exactly you want to get, selected image path or image content itself? If want to get image path, you can follow as told by : csteinmueller , of in the same selectionchanged event you can use : var selectedItem = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe hooking on the SelectionChanged event may help you?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
```

and in your codebehind file write a handler like this:

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

If you check e.AddedItems you should find your image in e.AddedItems[0].Image.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listview1}" Height="200" Width="180" />
```